# CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage for kCVPixelFormatType_OneComponent8

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, arkit, objective-c-runtime

I'm trying to use [`CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1619860-cvopenglestexturecachecreatetext?language=objc) in order to use the reference in OpenGL, with no luck:

I have a [`CVPixelBufferRef`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/cvpixelbufferref?language=objc) pixel_bufferAlpha which gets updated using [`CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1456979-cvpixelbuffercreatewithbytes), with success :
`CVReturn` is successfull.

Then I try to use [`CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1619860-cvopenglestexturecachecreatetext?language=objc) on a **1 channel texture** ( [alphaMatte](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/armattegenerator/3223424-generatematte) ) to create a [`CVOpenGLESTextureRef`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/cvopenglestextureref?language=objc) that i can use in OpenGL.

I have initialised my [`CVOpenGLESTextureCacheRef`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/cvopenglestexturecacheref?language=objc) _videoTextureAlphaCache :

```
err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreate(
                                        kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                        nil,
                                        eaglContext,
                                        nil,
                                        &_videoTextureAlphaCache);
```

And my `CVPixelBufferRef` pixel_bufferAlpha is initialised using :

```
 cvret = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                             width,height,
                                             kCVPixelFormatType_OneComponent8,
                                             (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)cvBufferProperties,
                                             &pixel_bufferAlpha);

        if(cvret != kCVReturnSuccess)
        {
            assert(!"Failed to create shared opengl pixel_bufferAlpha");
        }
```

I'm using `kCVPixelFormatType_OneComponent8`, as my `MTLTexture` passed in `CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes` has a `MTLPixelFormat`  10 - > MTLPixelFormatR8Unorm.

When trying to use `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage`, I get an error "not opengl compatible" :

```
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixel_bufferAlpha, 0);

        err = noErr;
        err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                           _videoTextureAlphaCache,
                                                           pixel_bufferAlpha,
                                                           NULL,
                                                           GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                                           // internal
                                                           // GL_RGBA,
                                                           GL_ALPHA,
                                                           width,
                                                           height,
                                                           // gl format
                                                           // GL_BGRA_EXT,
                                                           // GL_R8_EXT,
                                                           GL_ALPHA8_EXT,
                                                           // gl type
                                                           // GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV,
                                                           GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                                                           NULL,
                                                           &alphaTextureGLES);


        if (err != kCVReturnSuccess) {
            CVBufferRelease(pixel_bufferAlpha);

            if(err == kCVReturnInvalidPixelFormat){
                NSLog(@"Invalid pixel format");
            }

            if(err == kCVReturnInvalidPixelBufferAttributes){
                NSLog(@"Invalid pixel buffer attributes");
            }

            if(err == kCVReturnInvalidSize){
                NSLog(@"invalid size");
            }

            if(err == kCVReturnPixelBufferNotOpenGLCompatible){
                NSLog(@"CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage::not opengl compatible");
            }

        }else{
            NSLog(@"ok CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage SUCCESS");
        }

        // ================================================================================ //

        // clear texture cache
        CVOpenGLESTextureCacheFlush(_videoTextureAlphaCache, 0);
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixel_bufferAlpha, 0);
```

I'm not sure what I' doing wrong here.

**Also** I would appreciate any pointers as I'm not super versed in iOS and textures conversions / formats...

Best,

P

Full relevant part of the code :

```
alphaTexture = [matteDepthTexture  generateMatteFromFrame:_session.currentFrame commandBuffer:commandBuffer];

        // ===============================================================



        NSUInteger texBytesPerRow = alphaTexture.bufferBytesPerRow;
        NSUInteger texArrayLength = alphaTexture.arrayLength;




        int width = (int) alphaTexture.width;
        int height = (int) alphaTexture.height;
        MTLPixelFormat texPixelFormat = alphaTexture.pixelFormat;
        MTLTextureType texType = alphaTexture.textureType;
        int bytesPerPixel = 8;

        // MTLPixelFormatR8Unorm Ordinary format with one 8-bit normalized unsigned integer component.
        NSLog(@" texPixelFormat of the texture is : %d", texPixelFormat);
        NSLog(@" texType of the texture is : %d", texType);

        CVReturn err = noErr;
        err = CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                     width,
                                     height,
                                     kCVPixelFormatType_OneComponent8,
                                     alphaTexture,
                                     bytesPerPixel * width,
                                     stillImageDataReleaseCallback,
                                     alphaTexture,
                                     NULL,
                                     &pixel_bufferAlpha);

        if (err != kCVReturnSuccess) {

               if(err == kCVReturnInvalidPixelFormat){
                   NSLog(@"Invalid pixel format");
               }

               if(err == kCVReturnInvalidPixelBufferAttributes){
                   NSLog(@"Invalid pixel buffer attributes");
               }

               if(err == kCVReturnInvalidSize){
                   NSLog(@"invalid size");
               }

               if(err == kCVReturnPixelBufferNotOpenGLCompatible){
                   NSLog(@"CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes::not opengl compatible");
               }

        }else{
            NSLog(@"ok CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes SUCCESS");
        }

        OSType sourcePixelFormat = CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType(pixel_bufferAlpha);
        if (kCVPixelFormatType_OneComponent8 == sourcePixelFormat) {
           NSLog(@" got format kCVPixelFormatType_OneComponent8");
        } else{
           NSLog(@" Unknown CoreVideo pixel format : %a", sourcePixelFormat);
        }




        // ================================================================================ //
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixel_bufferAlpha, 0);

        err = noErr;
        err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                           _videoTextureAlphaCache,
                                                           pixel_bufferAlpha,
                                                           NULL,
                                                           GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                                           // internal
                                                           // GL_RGBA,
                                                           GL_RED_EXT,
                                                           width,
                                                           height,
                                                           // gl format
                                                           // GL_BGRA_EXT,
                                                           // GL_R8_EXT,
                                                           GL_R8_EXT,
                                                           // gl type
                                                           // GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV,
                                                           GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                                                           NULL,
                                                           &alphaTextureGLES);


        if (err != kCVReturnSuccess) {
            CVBufferRelease(pixel_bufferAlpha);

            if(err == kCVReturnInvalidPixelFormat){
                NSLog(@"Invalid pixel format");
            }

            if(err == kCVReturnInvalidPixelBufferAttributes){
                NSLog(@"Invalid pixel buffer attributes");
            }

            if(err == kCVReturnInvalidSize){
                NSLog(@"invalid size");
            }

            if(err == kCVReturnPixelBufferNotOpenGLCompatible){
                NSLog(@"CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage::not opengl compatible");
            }

        }else{
            NSLog(@"ok CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage SUCCESS");
        }

        // ================================================================================ //

        // clear texture cache
        CVOpenGLESTextureCacheFlush(_videoTextureAlphaCache, 0);
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixel_bufferAlpha, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

After digging a bit, I found an extension to MTLtexture from [Alloy](https://github.com/s1ddok/Alloy/tree/e146427d811a6816afae297afe496d6fcb42167f) - great work there - :

[here](https://github.com/s1ddok/Alloy/blob/e146427d811a6816afae297afe496d6fcb42167f/Alloy/CVPixelBuffer%2BMTLTexture.swift)

- `getBytes` to put the texture in a `CVPixelBufferRef` then
- `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage` to store it in a `CVOpenGLESTextureRef`.

So in Objective - C it looks like this -  with the same initialisation for the `pixel_bufferAlpha` and `_videoTextureAlphaCache` - :

```
        alphaTexture = [matteDepthTexture  generateMatteFromFrame:_session.currentFrame commandBuffer:commandBuffer];

        int width = (int) alphaTexture.width;
        int height = (int) alphaTexture.height;
        MTLPixelFormat texPixelFormat = alphaTexture.pixelFormat;


        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixel_bufferAlpha, 0);
        void * CV_NULLABLE pixelBufferBaseAdress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixel_bufferAlpha);
        size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixel_bufferAlpha);

         [alphaTexture getBytes:pixelBufferBaseAdress
                            bytesPerRow:bytesPerRow
                            fromRegion:MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, width, height)
                            mipmapLevel:0];


        size_t w = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixel_bufferAlpha);
        size_t h = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixel_bufferAlpha);

        CVReturn err = noErr;
        err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                        _videoTextureAlphaCache,
                                                        pixel_bufferAlpha,
                                                        nil,
                                                        GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D),
                                                        GLint(GL_LUMINANCE),
                                                        w,
                                                        h,
                                                        GLenum(GL_LUMINANCE),
                                                        GLenum(GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE),
                                                        0,
                                                        &alphaTextureGLES);


        if (err != kCVReturnSuccess) {
            CVBufferRelease(pixel_bufferAlpha);
            NSLog(@"error on CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage");
        }

        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixel_bufferAlpha, 0);
```

Hope this helps someone along the way.

Comment: Same question, but not work for me :(